# How to access AWS S3 Objects in a secure way

Tags: python, amazon-s3

What is the recommended way to let users access files that are stored on AWS S3?

I've currently found two ways:

- using the *access key ID* and *secret access key*
- making the whole bucket public and then accessing the files thru a public link.

Both options aren't really satisfying. Either I reveal the access/secret keys or all files are publicly available. Is there another third more secure way?

The software, that needs access to S3, will be running on Raspberry Pis. I was thinking of encrypting the credentials file, so a user wouldn't be able to read it easily.

Comment: *"I was thinking of encrypting the credentials file"*  Delete that thought from your mind.  https://techcrunch.com/2018/12/27/guardzilla-security-camera-flaws/

Comment: Thanks for the info, any advise on what to preferably do?

Comment: It depends on the what kind of entity is a "user" (person, machine, or person+machine), what kind of actions (read, write), your overall security model, and what kind of authentication you might already have available or want to use.  You could use [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) for example, to authenticate these users and hand out short-lived temporary IAM credentials with user-specific permissions or you could use [AWS IoT Core](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/) with client certificates.  It depends on more details about the nature of your setup than are provided so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is, to create a new individual AWS user with access key ID and secret for your project with and give the individual S3 permission to that user. Don't use admin credentials for a project. Every project should have a particular AWS user with its credentials and permissions. The second thing is, to rotate keys. So you create a new key with an old one and delete old key. More about rotation you can refer to [Managing Access Keys for IAM Users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html) documentation. Indeed, you can also encrypt it and AWS has the service [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_AE&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=key_management_b&sc_content=aws_kms_e&sc_detail=aws%20kms&sc_category=key_management&sc_segment=161342872296&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=AE&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!161342872296!e!!g!!aws%20kms&ef_id=CjwKCAiAyrXiBRAjEiwATI95mS-7c_xXEWGsLfZEmn5E27vumSP-i0vWYaF_g5WKAK2LMi-G2vaxshoC83sQAvD_BwE:G:s). You can make research in AWS KMS service, it is a great tool for encryption. You can even encrypt your application vulnerable secret keys or passwords.

Comment: So just to make sure I understood you. I create a user (let's say _customer_) in IAM. This user only gets absolutely necessary permissions to download files from my S3 project/bucket. I programmatically include that user in the software that's running on all the Pis and rotate the keys every 30/60/90 days. For additional security I could use AWS KMS to encrypt the credential file or other stuff that could be vulnerable

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is the best practices of AWS Credentials. I assume, there will be also other options in order to take precautions but if you follow these rules, the chance will be small that you will have some credential leak